# WooCommerce: add a discount after payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a payment method that add a discount according user payment option.

My problem now is I need to update order value after checkout, adding this discount value.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', function($order_id){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $pagseguro_payment_type = $order->get_meta('Tipo de pagamento');
    if('Boleto' == $pagseguro_payment_type){
        $order->set_discount_total('55');
    }
});
```

Without success.

My expectation is to show the discount amount on the dashboard.

Comment: Why would you do this after payment and not before?

Comment: @justkidding96 Because the discount is applied using a specific payment plugin action that run in checkout.

Comment: You can change the order price instead of applying discount.

Comment: @justkidding96 I try `$order->set_total('200.89')` without sucess. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to check out Bulk Discount plugin at this page:
https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-bulk-discount/

Comment: See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but try this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', function($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $order->set_price($price);
});
```

Comment: set_price() return error. I try set_total() but not work.

Comment: Try to output the order: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($order); ` what is the result?

Comment: Return the whole $order object.

Comment: Check if the order_id is the same as a post_id. if so try to update the price with this. `update_post_meta($order_id, _order_total', (float) $price);`